# Radar Chart Comparison - Aggregate Data - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, radar-chart, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to create a radar chart which allows me to aggregate data and allow me to control the aggregations with slicers. I have the following table with data ready prepared in Power Query with all the unpivoting done. The following table is called Sheet1.

| ID | Continent | Country | City | Year | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Europe | Germany | Berlin | 2021 | F1 | 50 |
| 1 | Europe | Germany | Berlin | 2021 | F2 | 60 |
| 1 | Europe | Germany | Berlin | 2021 | F3 | 76 |
| 1 | Europe | Germany | Berlin | 2021 | F4 | 80 |
| 1 | Europe | Germany | Berlin | 2021 | F5 | 30 |
| 2 | Africa | Nigeria | Lagos | 2022 | F1 | 23 |
| 2 | Africa | Nigeria | Lagos | 2022 | F2 | 11 |
| 2 | Africa | Nigeria | Lagos | 2022 | F3 | 23 |
| 2 | Africa | Nigeria | Lagos | 2022 | F4 | 23 |
| 2 | Africa | Nigeria | Lagos | 2022 | F5 | 30 |
| 2 | Africa | Nigeria | Lagos | 2022 | F6 | 64 |
| 3 | Asia | Japan | Tokyo | 2021 | F1 | 34 |
| 3 | Asia | Japan | Tokyo | 2021 | F3 | 32 |
| 4 | Asia | Japan | Tokyo | 2021 | F1 | 45 |

Averaging everything for the year is easy, with an extra table named Year, with one column also named Year and 2 rows, 2021 and 2022. This column goes into a slicer.

| Year |
| --- |
| 2021 |
| 2022 |

The category will be Sheet1[Attribute] and the following measure going to the Y Axis:

```
_value-slicer_Avg = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Year'[Year]),
                        2021,
                           CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Sheet1[Value]),Sheet1[Year]=2021),
                        2022,
                           CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Sheet1[Value]),Sheet1[Year]=2022)
                    )
```

This yields the average for a year of choice, when I drop the Year column of the Year table into the slicer

[Average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sECx.png)

What I want to be able to, is to add another dataset on top of it, which would be easy in case of the data of an ID only (see the Individual Comparison tab of the attached pbix)

Duplicating the table in PowerQuery (no relations needed) as below...

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBH9o.png)

...I need to create these measures:

```
_slicer_individual_selection = 
        SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1_New[ID])

_value-slicer_individual_selection = 
        CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Sheet1[Value]),FILTER(Sheet1, Sheet1[ID] = [_slicer_individual_selection]))
```

And drop the ID of the Sheet1_New table in another slicer.

[Individual Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShSDm.png)

What I want however, is for the second dataset to be the set of the averages of the IDs selected, and the selection should be available at Continent, Country, City or ID level (see the Aggregate Comparison tab of the pbix file attached).

My attempt is not correct, but for the sake of illustration, here it is:

I have replaced the following measure in the Y Axis of the radar chart:

```
_value-slicer_individual_selection
```

with this one

```
_value-slicer_multiple_selection = 
        CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Sheet1[Value]),FILTER(Sheet1, Sheet1[ID] IN ALLSELECTED(Sheet1_New[ID])))
```

[Failed Attempt of Aggregate Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N537H.png)

It also doesn't let me see all the continents, countries, cities or IDs available, I have to keep selecting things to make them show up. I want to be able to show the aggregate set of any selection of IDs based on the supersets available (continent, country, city) as the second set on top of the original aggregate per year. In the above example, I want to see the average for all the data from Tokyo (please note: for 2021 only) as the second set.

Also, I want the 4 slicers on the right-hand side to update, so that I only get to select the ones for 2021 when the selected Year is 2021 and the same for 2022.

Attachments are not supported, please download them from here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aHS0kFCIUe407bS59VF_MUhrLygc5wfh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your case I'd do following:

1. Remove YEAR table and substitute values in the slicer With Sheet1[Year]. All other slicer make of Sheet1 columns.
   Substitute `Sheet1_New` with `Attributes`. Link `Attributes[Attribute]` to `Sheet1[Attribute]`. Use `Attributes[Attribute]` for category in the chart. If you don't want the link then use `TREATAS()`, but it will slower the measure. The reason for `Attributes[Attribute]` is that if you use `Sheet1[Attribute]` as category in the chart, you may filter Attribute values and it will distroy the chart.
2. Change your `_value-slicer_Avg` to:

---

```
 _value-slicer_Avg = 
     CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE(Sheet1[Value])
        ,ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1,Sheet1[Attribute],Sheet1[Year])
    )
```

3. All your Other measures do like this:

---

```
 _value-slicer_individual_selection = 
     CALCULATE(
         AVERAGE(Sheet1[Value])
        ,ALLEXCEPT(
            Sheet1
            ,Sheet1[Year]
            ,Sheet1[Attribute]
            ,Sheet1[ID]
        )
    )
```

4. Make your slicers not influencing `Sheet1[Year]` slicer and each other except chart. `Sheet1[Year]` should filter all visuals. Chart should not infuence any sclicer. look at pictures

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can create table with unique values of Attibutes as follows:

```
Attributes = VALUES(Sheet1[Attribute])
```

I didn't link it with a Sheet1, so TREATAS was added.
Below the measure which works with multiple selection.

```
_Avg = 
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE(Sheet1[Value])
        ,TREATAS(Attributes,Sheet1[Attribute])
    )
```

This measure will show average in respect of year only

```
_value-slicer_Avg = 
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE(Sheet1[Value])
        ,ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1,Sheet1[Year])
        ,TREATAS(Attributes,Sheet1[Attribute])
    )
```

Regarding slicer look at the picture below:

[image]

Try to adjust filtering of slicers and the chart as you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have a suggestion for me to see the aggregate average data for multiple IDs, based on a selection of a superset, such as the city, country or continent? If I select Japan for example, I would like to be able to see the average attributes of all the IDs from Japan for that year as the second graph on the radar chart. Would be ideal to manipulate this from slicers only, so I pick whichever set of IDs I need to aggregate.

Comment: Ok, I’ll think about it on Sunday.

Comment: You can try it right now. Make a slicer of country column. Copy the last measure in my answer. Replace I’d with country in ALLEXCEPT()

Comment: But how you gonna show all this graphs at once? Or you plan to have only  2?

Comment: What if you create several charts , so you would not have a mess with all info at one point.

Comment: Thank you again for looking into this, I appreciate your effort very much. I will need 2 charts, one on top of the other. The first one will stay put as the set of averages of all IDs for the selected year and the second one will be the set of averages of the IDs selected, which has to be controlled from slicers easily to cover any superset available for the chosen year. This is the requirement I have received unfortunately and I have spent the whole day trying to make this in an R script, hoping it would be more flexible, but it got so much harder, so I will need to return to DAX.

Comment: I have tried your solution, and unfortunately, it does not help me aggregate. Making the slicers not interact with each other is not very clear to me, especially because next to ID I have the superset slicers too. In fact, I do want them to influence each other, since year 2021 for example should allow me to select only IDs of that year. What I was trying before is this, making the slicers show items when the value is 1:

Category = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('First Year Selection'[Year]) <> SELECTEDVALUE('2021-2022 Agency Criteria Scoring_New'[Year]),
    0,
    1
)

Comment: Note that I tried a relationship as you mentioned on the Attributes[Attribute] and Sheet1[Attribute], but it is many-to-many and I cannot make it active - it's blocked by another relationship in my model. I have merged several fields into a new column to make it one-to-one, but it still did not actually do what I needed to (seems stuck). I have another field named Quarter by the way, so the values you see in the sample dummy data from Excel are not necessarily unique by the (ID, Attribute) pair. The same attribute for the same ID could have been evaluated multiple times through the same year.

Comment: I alterd the answer. So, please look at.